# ESLint and TypeScript complaining in MongoDB script file

Tags: mongodb, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm writing a `mongodb` script file with the suffix `.js`:

```
// @ts-nocheck
/* eslint-disable no-undef */

// Add admin
use admin;
```

I get the following error though when I however over `admin`:

```
any
Parsing error: Unexpected token admineslint
';' expected.ts(1005)
Peek Problem
No quick fixes available
```

How does one write a mongodb script file so that `eslint` and `typescript` in `vscode` don't complain?

Comment: One way seems to be adding ```// @ts-nocheck``` at the top of the file

Comment: @JCOlivares Haha look at my code example dude.

Comment: oops... well, that's all I have. I'm sorry.